# UPSERT in PostgreSQL Table , DBeaver SQL Editor , SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "for" Position: 10

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, amazon-rds, plpgsql

I am having two postgresql rds db table

```
Table dummy_data_03032021

imjp_number              imct_id
81854915787907305851    _HxH-CMAws4AqHozXxuEAQ
6027753261008842022 e5bd5uCPWyUDdvB0fZS6ow
72936468298302871360    u5MWlSrPjJkDZAyBKxvBbg
186730481830914821  z9aqy18QxC_OA3AZ9NxZgw
23220329619113353680    Gp8ejcols_ARgXE_oQiNvA
55982335263910501268    6rrjZNt-ujJeoGkIL7M4lA
82054204424171183823    s7aWLWm8C9ZTPqXpFrcn4Q
```

AND

```
   Table dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021
jp_number(Varchar)                ct_id(text)                  C2,C3.......C40
25146315052147720191     e5bd5uCPWyUDdvB0fZS6ow                  V2,V3.......V40
6027753261008842022      [NULL]
86076681691411639833     Gp8ejcols_ARgXE_oQiNvA
50491824499499656478     [NULL]
82054204424171183823     [NULL]
```

I am updating ct_id value into table dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 from dummy_data_03032021 if jpnumber=imjp_number
otherwise I have to insert both jp_number and ct_id value into table dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 from dummy_data_03032021 keeping other column value intact

I tried to write query as below but getting error like"SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "for"   Position: 10"

```
select imjp_number into temptbl from dummy_data_03032021

select * from temptbl

begin 
    for i in select * from temptbl
    loop
    @ set iv_ctid text
    set iv_ctid=SELECT imct_id from dummy_data_03032021 where imjp_number=i
    @ set cnt int
    SET cnt=SELECT count(jp_number) FROM dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 WHERE jp_numbner=i
        if cnt=0 then execute insert into dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021(jp_number,ct_id) values(i,iv_ctid);
        else
        execute update dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 set ct_id=iv_ctid WHERE jpnumber=i; 
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Please Rectify me If any syntax and query declaration is incorrect , I am beginner in PostgreSQL and DBeaver

Note:---Question Edited ! imct_id changed to ct_id in dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 and duplicate 82054204424171183823,6027753261008842022 number added in both table

I have fiddle link:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=62c061f9e8becbe0e7e54263218cbff5

please rectify it ,

insert into dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 (jp_number, ct_id)
select imjp_number, imct_id
from dummy_data_03032021
on conflict (jp_number) do update
set ct_id = imct_id;

gives error like below:SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "imct_id" does not exist
Hint: There is a column named "imct_id" in table "*SELECT*", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
Position: 167

Comment: [Variable assignment in PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) is done  using `:=` not `SET`  and `@ set iv_ctid text` is completely invalid - I don't understand what that is supposed to be. You also don't need `execute` to run static SQL - that's only needed for dynamic SQL

Comment: I don't think you need PL/pgSQL to begin with. As far as I can tell this can be done with an `insert on conflict` or if you don't have a unique constraint, use one INSERT and one UPDATE https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=62c061f9e8becbe0e7e54263218cbff5

Comment: I got    SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "imct_id" does not exist
  Hint: There is a column named "imct_id" in table "*SELECT*", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
  Position: 160  error , when executed Your query "insert into dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 (jp_number, ct_id) select imjp_number, imct_id from dummy_data_03032021 on conflict (jp_number) do update set ct_id = imct_id;"

Comment: That's not what my fiddle contains.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Question Edited ! imct_id changed to ct_id in dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 and duplicate 82054204424171183823,6027753261008842022  number added

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I corrected my mistake "insert into dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 (jp_number, ct_id) select imjp_number, imct_id from dummy_data_03032021 on conflict (jp_number) do update set ct_id = excluded.ct_id;
" But Got this error SQL Error [42P10]: ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification, Please Help@a_horse_with_no_name